# How to print a value of a JSON file on the screen with Java?

Tags: java, json, api

I recently started using the OKHttp library to make requests to an API, this is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/players/player/874")
        .get()
        .addHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com")
        .addHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "6147bd5da4mshfacf56a7067aa5ep1ff9e6jsn60984dedb281")
        .build();

    okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
}
```

Now, I would like to know how to print the value that has the string "firstname" as the "key".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the String from `Response` :

```
String stringResponse = response.body().string();
```

Then you have to parse the JSON contained in the String.
For this, you can use org.json :

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(stringResponse);
String firstName = jsonResponse.getString("firstName");
```

Or maybe use Jackson to parse JSON if you can map your JSON to an class you have.

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(response);
String firstname = responseJson .get("firstname").toString();

I think this should work for you.